# What if I've sabotaged my Chanukah candles?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, menora-chanukia

The halacha as codified in [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 673:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3053) is that if your Chanukah candles go out before the time period of their burning has elapsed, you do not need to relight them.

The Rashba was asked (Responsa 1:539) about if you inadvertently cause your lights to go out while trying to fix them, and responded that you still do not need to relight them.

What if someone wants to save themselves some oil expense, and intentionally puts out their own candles?  Would they then have to relight them, or would the same thing apply?

Comment: +1. Also relevant to a situation where you have to leave, and you don't want to leave the candles unattended.

Comment: @Shokhet I believe that YeZ is asking about before the requisite amount of time for lighting is up, whereas if the time has already passed, the Shulchan Aruch states explicitly in [O"C 572:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=283&hilite=) that one may put out the candles

Comment: @YEZ a possible nafka mina could be if one lit originally with the intention of blowing them out, or came up with the idea afterwards.

Comment: @Jewels What about if you have to leave.... *before* the time is up?

Answer (score 4):

The Shulchan Aruch does say "בשוגג" (inadvertently) as you pointed out. Not eve discussing doing it on purpose.

[Here](http://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=25107) (though unsourced) it says you would need to relight, without a bracha (near the end)

[Rav Dov Lior explains](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/9355) (part b) the relevant Talmud ([Shabbat 21b](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=21b&format=pdf)) and states (end of first paragraph) that one would not need to relight if it went out, but not put it out on purpose. He seems to be saying it of common sense.

[Another place](http://www.ygolan.org/play.php?les=1086) I found brings a disagreement between Rashi & Tosfot explaining that Rashi says you do not need to relight only if it wasn't on purpose, while Tosfot says even in case of אונס the mitzva would not be fulfilled.